# fractional ideals = R submodules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let K be a number field and R its ring of integers.  Are the fractional ideals of K just the R submodules of K?

Comment: The standard definition says that fractional ideals are those $R$-submodules $I$ of $K$ for which there exists a nonzero $r\in R$ with $rI \subseteq R$. What makes you think that second condition might be redundant?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg i see, thank you. that was not quite the def i was working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not. For example, $K$ itself is obviously an $R$-submodule of $K$, but it's not a fractional ideal.

Comment: thank you. what if i say  "finitely generated R module"? then its true, right?

Comment: For $R$ the ring of integers of a number field as in your question, yes. In more general situations, no.